# Python 3.4, TypeError for socket issues

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I don't quite understand the encode/decode in python. 
I've tried alsorts and looked here to find similar but I cannot find some.
This is the code in question:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading
import time

QUIT = False


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):  # Class that implements the client threads in this server
    def __init__(self, client_sock):  # Initialize the object, save the socket that this thread will use.
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client_sock

    def run(self):  # Thread's main loop. Once this function returns, the thread is finished and dies.
        global QUIT  # Need to declare QUIT as global, since the method can change it
        done = False
        cmd = self.readline()  # Read data from the socket and process it
        while not done:
            if b'quit' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye')
                QUIT = True
                done = True
            elif b'bye' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye')
                done = True
            else:
                self.writeline(self.name).encode('utf-8')
                cmd = self.readline()

            self.client.close()  # Make sure socket is closed when we're done with it
            return

    def readline(self):  # Helper function, read up to 1024 chars from the socket, and returns them as a string
        result = self.client.recv(1024)
        if None != result:  # All letters in lower case and without and end of line markers
            result = result.strip().lower()
        return result

    def writeline(self, text):  # Helper func, writes the given string to the socket with and end of line marker at end
        self.client.send(bytes(text.strip() + '\n'))
```

In this case, I get:

```
TypeError: string argument without an enconding.
```

This is on the line:

```
self.writeline('ok bye')
```

and also the line:

```
self.client.send(bytes(text.strip() + '\n'))
```

deleting the bytes part gives me another error:

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

And also references the two lines from above.
I've tried a combination of `encode(utf-8)` on both with no help.
I think I'm grossly misunderstanding what is wrong here. I know that `bytes` need to be sent, but when I do, it gives a concatenated error. Stuck in a vile loop.
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

This is the full code with the additions from the community help thus far:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading
import time

QUIT = False


class ClientThread(threading.Thread):  # Class that implements the client threads in this server
    def __init__(self, client_sock):  # Initialize the object, save the socket that this thread will use.
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client_sock

    def run(self):  # Thread's main loop. Once this function returns, the thread is finished and dies.
        global QUIT  # Need to declare QUIT as global, since the method can change it
        done = False
        cmd = self.readline()  # Read data from the socket and process it
        while not done:
            if b'quit' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye'.encode('utf-8'))
                QUIT = True
                done = True
            elif b'bye' == cmd:
                self.writeline('Ok, bye')
                done = True
            else:
                self.writeline(str(self.name).encode('utf-8'))
                cmd = self.readline()

            self.client.close()  # Make sure socket is closed when we're done with it
            return

    def readline(self):  # Helper function, read up to 1024 chars from the socket, and returns them as a string
        result = self.client.recv(1024)
        if None != result:  # All letters in lower case and without and end of line markers
            result = result.strip().lower()
        return result

    def writeline(self, text):  # Helper func, writes the given string to the socket with and end of line marker at end
        self.client.send((text.strip() + '\n').encode("utf-8"))


class Server:  # Server class. Opens up a socket and listens for incoming connections.
    def __init__(self):  # Every time a new connection arrives, new thread object is created and
        self.sock = None  # defers the processing of the connection to it
        self.thread_list = []

    def run(self):  # Server main loop: Creates the server (incoming) socket, listens > creates thread to handle it
        all_good = False
        try_count = 0  # Attempt to open the socket
        while not all_good:
            if 3 < try_count:  # Tried more than 3 times without success, maybe post is in use by another program
                sys.exit(1)
            try:
                self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Create the socket
                port = 80
                self.sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))  # Bind to the interface and port we want to listen on
                self.sock.listen(5)
                all_good = True
                break
            except socket.error:
                print('Socket connection error... Waiting 10 seconds to retry.')
                del self.sock
                time.sleep(10)
                try_count += 1

        print('Server is listening for incoming connections.')
        print('Try to connect through the command line with:')
        print('telnet localhost 80')
        print('and then type whatever you want.')
        print()
        print("typing 'bye' finishes the thread. but not the server",)
        print("eg. you can quit telnet, run it again and get a different ",)
        print("thread name")
        print("typing 'quit' finishes the server")

        try:
            while not QUIT:
                try:
                    self.sock.settimeout(0.500)
                    client = self.sock.accept()[0]
                except socket.timeout:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if QUIT:
                        print('Received quit command. Shutting down...')
                        break
                    continue
                new_thread = ClientThread(client)
                print('Incoming Connection. Started thread ',)
                print(new_thread.getName())
                self.thread_list.append(new_thread)
                new_thread.start()
                for thread in self.thread_list:
                    if not thread.isAlive():
                        self.thread_list.remove(thread)
                        thread.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Ctrl+C pressed... Shutting Down')
        except Exception as err:
            print('Exception caught: %s\nClosing...' % err)
        for thread in self.thread_list:
            thread.join(1.0)
            self.sock.close()

if "__main__" == __name__:
    server = Server()
    server.run()

print('Terminated')
```

In the traceback I get this exactly:

```
Exception in Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File: "C:\Python34\liv\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
         self.run()
File: "C:/Users/Savag/PycharmProjects/lds_system/Socketthread2.py", line 20 in run
         self.writeline('Ok, bye'.encode("utf-8"))
File: "C:/Users/Savag/PycharmProjects/lds_system/Socketthread2.py", Line 40, in writeline
self.client.send((text.strip() + '\n').encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: So how did the `str.encode('utf8')` attempt fail exactly? You need to explicitly encode your text, using `str.encode()` *is* the right way, but clearly that failed for you.

Comment: It said, can't concat bytes to str.
this is how I wrote it:
        `self.writeline('ok, bye'.encode('utf-8'))`
and also
        `self.client.send(text.strip() + '\n').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: This might be one of your problems: You have this line: `self.writeline(self.name).encode('utf-8')`, that is you call `encode`on the return value of `writeline()`. Yet, `writeline` does not return anything. To properly encode the string, you would do `str("your string").encode("utf-8")`

Comment: @Savagefool: you have to encode *everything before you send it*, so the latter should be `self.client.send((text.strip() + '\n').encode('utf-8'))`.

Comment: @Savagefool: please include that attempt in your question with the full traceback of the exception; you are still using a `str` object somewhere and it is being concatenated to a `bytes` object, possibly the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `self.writeline('Ok bye'.encode('utf8'))` you are now passing a `bytes` object to your `writeline()` method. In that method, you are then concatenating another string to it `text.strip() + '\n'`, causing you to try to concatenate a `bytes` and a `str` object.

Either have your `writeline` method handle the encoding, or have it handle `bytes` only. If you do the latter, make sure your `readline()` method then *decodes* the data it reads from the socket, to be consistent.

In other words, pick an abstraction level at which you convert from text to bytes, and use it consistently:

```
def readline(self):
    """Read up to 1024 bytes and return this as a string

    Returns None if there was no data to read.

    """
    result = self.client.recv(1024)
    if result is not None:
        result = result.strip().lower().decode('utf8')
    return result

def writeline(self, text):
    """Write a string to the socket, followed by a newline"""
    self.client.send(text.strip().encode('utf8') + b'\n')
```

Note that I used a `b'...'` bytes literal to create a `bytes` object for the newline to concatenate.

Here `writeline` encodes, so pass in *string objects* when you call the object:

```
self.writeline('Ok, bye')
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy replies ewriten to exactly what you wrote here.
I then get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: I did tell you to call `writeline()` passing in `str` objects only. You are still calling it with a `bytes` object. Do **not** use `self.writeline('Ok, bye'.encode('utf8'))`, you don't need to encode *twice*.

Comment: Yep got that, removed all the encode on the 'ok, bye'. I wrote this exactly as you did. :(

Comment: Look closely at your traceback. Check what the `writeline()` call looks like in that traceback. Make sure you are running up-to-date code (e.g. you made sure to restart your server after changing the code).

Comment: With that way of receiving the bytes you may wish to encode using `"ascii"` rather than `"utf8"`. With `"utf-8"` you run the risk of splitting a multi-byte encoding (when receiving the bytes like that).

Comment: Awesome, this worked exactly. Switching to ascii too, to account for that error, thank you two very much.